# Bash : grep unique lines

Tags: bash, grep, uniq

I'd like to `grep` unique line. This is the file content:

```
this is line 1
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 1
this is line 1
```

I just want to output `this is line 2` to my shell.
How can I do that?

Comment: did you even look around a little bit? http://superuser.com/q/111430/311327

Comment: The title ask for "non unique" while the body clearly describe "unique".  
For those who want non unique lines, use `grep "this is line" <file> | sort | uniq -d`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sort x.txt |uniq -u
```

assuming your file is in x.txt which gives

```
this is line 2
```

Comment: Oddly enough, you don't always need to sort, even when the text isn't already in order -- I'm not sure when that changed.

Comment: I was looking at that too, if you have a one line "this is line 1" at the end it will show it

Comment: Not the case on the BSD uniq on more recent OSX and Linux distros.  If you know that's the case, you can save yourself a proc and sending the data over a pipe.

Comment: @tristan What implementation of `uniq` are you looking at? GNU coreutils 8.23 can still filter only adjacent lines.

Answer (score 5):

Check out `man uniq`:

```
 -u      Only output lines that are not repeated in the input.
```

With that in mind, sort does a pairwise comparison to see if it's neighbor matches, meaning that you need to sort your output before feeding it to `uniq`:

$ `sort my_list.txt | uniq -u`

Comment: Nice: always better when no pipe needed

Comment: but as @keepcalmandcarryon notices: if you have only one "line 1" at the end; it will show up...

Comment: yep. editing because the future isn't as magical as i thought at 230am

Answer (score 4):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk '{a[$0]++} END {for (i in a) if (a[i]==1) print i}' file
this is line 2
```